# Function that returns a value as large as the mouse is near the center

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

As the title say, I'm looking for a function that detect when the mouse is approaching the center.
Here is what I've done until now:

```
   var posX = mouseX;
   if(posX > width/2) {
      posX = width - posX;
   }
   posX = map(posX, 0, width/2, 0, 1);

   var posY = mouseY;
   if(posY > height/2) {
      posY = height - posY;
   }
   posY = map(posY, 0, height/2, 0, 1);

   speed = map(posX+posY, 0, 2, 0, 30);
```

As you imagine, it's not working very well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple function, which calculates the distance between two points (`d = sqrt(dx² + dy²)`):

```
function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2){
   return Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
}
```

and call it like

```
var d = distance(mouseX,mouseY,width*0.5,height*0.5);
```

and to map it you need the maximum distance from the center, which is the distance between the center and one of the corners

```
var dMax = distance(0,0,width*0.5,height*0.5);
```

Then you can simply map it to whatever you like:

```
var mapped = map(d,0,dMax,0,1);
```

Comment: Thank you!
There is actually a function dist() in p5.js, so I didn't have to re-write it.